# Empirical shuffle check python

Tags: python

Empirical shuffle check. Run computational experiments to check that our shuffling
code works as advertised. Compose a program that takes integer command-line arguments m and n, does n shuffles of an array of size m that is initialized with a[i] = i
before each shuffle, and writes an m-by-m table such that row i gives the number of
times i wound up in position j for all j. All entries in the array should be close to n/m.

I'm trying to shuffle an array in python. My code goes like this:

```py
import random
import sys

m = int(sys.argv[1])
n = int(sys.argv[2])
a = []      # a[i] = i
res =[]     # for resit the array as a

for i in range(m):
    a.append(i) # a[i] = i
res = a.copy()

for i in range(n):
    random.shuffle(a)
    print(a)
    # i can't understand how to print m-m table that i gives number of times of i wound up
    # in position j for all j.
    a = res.copy()

print(n/m)
```

Comment: So what exactly is your *question*?

Comment: I can't understand how to print m-m table that i gives number of times of i wound up in position j for all j.